# Chrome doesn't show WEBP images in production

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, webp

While works perfectly locally, Chrome doesn't render WEBP images after app deployment.
Neither via picture tag, nor via standard img.
Website for reference: https://neuralle-staging.herokuapp.com/case-study-resources

Example:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://cdn.neuralle.com/assets/v2/case_studies/lwc-24ac69b1ab68da006ef9e1ecc8bd9025aaf646a684235811b9b2afa9efebc07e.webp" type="image/webp" class="lazyloading">
  <source srcset="https://cdn.neuralle.com/assets/v2/case_studies/lwc-0fa311dd3dd17a0092d6ad606a31b16b7184de62c7bfebe9c3181ff811a95ea8.jpg" class="lazyloading">
  <img src="https://cdn.neuralle.com/assets/v2/case_studies/lwc-0fa311dd3dd17a0092d6ad606a31b16b7184de62c7bfebe9c3181ff811a95ea8.jpg" class="lazyloaded">
</picture>
```

Also, everything works fine with Safari, Firefox, or Chrome mobile, and I can download this image and open in my operating system.

Another weird thing is if I open the image directly in the browser, it opens as a text document (only when the app is deployed – I can open it as usual locally): https://cdn.neuralle.com/assets/v2/case_studies/lwc-24ac69b1ab68da006ef9e1ecc8bd9025aaf646a684235811b9b2afa9efebc07e.webp

And yes, it has nothing to do with lazyloading.

So it seems that something goes wrong when the image is hosted on the remote server. I use Ruby on Rails 6, so might be something with assets precompilation, but can't say for sure.

I tried Chrome 88, both Win and Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the app is fetching assets via CDN (Cloudflare), and for some reason, Cloudflare couldn't serve WEBP images properly.

Found the culprit.

I also read that there is a free account restriction, so I disabled CDN for now.